# Creating partition for Diskwarrior

Tags: mac, optical-drive

I am fixing my friend's '07 MacBook Pro.  The superdrive keeps spitting out discs and the harddrive is corrupt.  I want to run Disk Warrior 4.4 but can't because of the Superdrive problem. The computer has two partitions.  I erased the second, XP one and now it's available as a Mac Drive.  My question is, can I mount the Diskwarrior program on this drive in such a way that I can boot into it as if it was a Boot CD?  I'm a PC technician and so am a little lost with the finer details of Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options:

1)  Use an external DVD drive connected via USB to boot into the Disk Warrior DVD

I use a spare IDE DVD-R drive from an old PC connected with a Newer Tech USB to IDE adapter.  I have had to do this a few times with a Mac Mini Server.  The only problem is that booting this way is VERY slow.

2)  If you have access to another Mac, connect the problem machine to the good mac with a Firewire cable and boot the damaged machine holding down the "T" key to enter Firewire Target Disk Mode

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Then run Disk Warrior from the good Mac on the problem Mac's drive.

For the future:  These are better options but probably not as easy at this point.

I try to have a USB flash drive around with a clone (via Carbon Copy Cloner) of a working system that contains the emergency utilities like Disk Warrior.  I can then boot from it if needed.

I also like keeping a bootable clone on an external hard drive with Disk Warrior already installed as part of my backup strategy.

You can select an alternate boot volume when turning on the machine by holding down the `<option>` key.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer.  I will likely try the Firewire target solution ...